# Delete and Insert transaction still causing violation c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

I have been running an application and have just looked at the error log it produces. I am getting multiple errors for primary key violations. Having looked at the source code that performs the action I cannot understand why this is occurring.

The application is written in C# on Dotnet Core and does not use an ORM framework instead it uses `SqlObjects`.

The command updates the table using a `DbCommand` transaction. AS I said I am getting a Primary Key violation even though the command itself removes the entry before resubmitting with an updated time. I cannot seem to understand why this is the case especially when SqlCommand is supposed to be a transaction.

Command

```
_sqlObjectFactory.GetConnection()
    .Using(connection =>
    {
        var command = connection.Command(
                _sqlObjectFactory, "DELETE FROM pf_ServiceHeartbeat WHERE ServiceName = @ServiceName AND MachineName = @MachineName")
            .AddParameter(_sqlObjectFactory, "@ServiceName", serviceName)
            .AddParameter(_sqlObjectFactory, "@MachineName", machineName);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO pf_ServiceHeartbeat (ServiceName, MachineName, LastRun) VALUES (@ServiceName, @MachineName, @LastRun)";
        command.AddParameter(_sqlObjectFactory, "@LastRun", lastRun);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    });
```

Error Log

```
Error: 11/07/2017 12:50:20 - SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_pf_ServiceHeartbeat'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.pf_ServiceHeartbeat'. The duplicate key value is (PopForums.Email.EmailApplicationService, MACHINENAME).
The statement has been terminated.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at PopForums.Data.Sql.Repositories.ServiceHeartbeatRepository.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(DbConnection connection) in E:\Projects\Forum\src\PopForums.Sql\Repositories\ServiceHeartbeatRepository.cs:line 40
at PopForums.Data.Sql.Extensions.Using(DbConnection connection, Action`1 action) in E:\Projects\Forum\src\PopForums.Sql\Extensions.cs:line 53
at PopForums.Data.Sql.Repositories.ServiceHeartbeatRepository.RecordHeartbeat1(String serviceName, String machineName, DateTime lastRun) in E:\Projects\Forum\src\PopForums.Sql\Repositories\ServiceHeartbeatRepository.cs:line 32
at PopForums.Services.ServiceHeartbeatService.Add(String serviceName, String machineName) in E:\Projects\Forum\src\PopForums\Services\ServiceHeartbeatService.cs:line 37
at PopForums.Services.ServiceHeartbeatService.RecordHeartbeat(String serviceName, String machineName) in E:\Projects\Forum\src\PopForums\Services\ServiceHeartbeatService.cs:line 25
at PopForums.Services.ApplicationServiceBase.Execute(Object sender) in E:\Projects\Forum\src\PopForums\Services\ApplicationServiceBase.cs:line 50

HelpLink.ProdName: Microsoft SQL Server
HelpLink.ProdVer: 13.00.4422
HelpLink.EvtSrc: MSSQLServer
HelpLink.EvtID: 2627
HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
HelpLink.LinkId: 20476
```

**Updated**

Below is the definition of the serviceHeartbeat table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pf_ServiceHeartbeat](
    [ServiceName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [MachineName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LastRun] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_pf_ServiceHeartbeat] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ServiceName] ASC,
    [MachineName] ASC
)
)
```

Comment: Share the table definition and the definition of `PK_pf_ServiceHeartbeat`. Without this info, it's guesswork.

Comment: `The duplicate key value is (PopForums.Email.EmailApplicationService, MACHINENAME).' it says MACHINENAME is a PK. Check table definition.

Comment: choose a unique value for column `MACHINENAME` 
the name you are inserting already exists in this column.

Comment: @ARr0w the app is running on the same machine and therefore the delete statement should have removed it. Should it not?

Comment: Reapply your parameters to your insert statement

Comment: @Serg But there is a delete statement before the insert. So it should not be there when the insert takes place hence there should be no primary key violation

Comment: @LaurentLequenne If I reapply the parameters again then I get a duplicate variable name declared. Also, you can see the parameter within the stack trace e.g. `PopForums.Email.EmailApplicationService`

Comment: What's `SqlObjects`? Because it looks like ADO.NET, pops exceptions with stack traces to ADO.NET, and everything is just so ADO.NET, except the way you work with it.

Comment: Dear OP @sjc_w, have you found a solution yet? I'm facing the same problem, on .NET Core 2.1, where after `DELETE` all records, `INSERT` a record caused me `Violation of PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your situation, except for the `SqlObjects` for which Google is silent.

SQL Server 2017 preview, on Ubuntu 16.04

```
CREATE TABLE test.dbo.pf_ServiceHeartbeat (
    ServiceName nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
    MachineName nvarchar(256) NOT NULL,
    LastRun datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_pf_ServiceHeartbeat PRIMARY KEY (ServiceName,MachineName)
)
```

Project (csproj) file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.Common" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

C# code (Dotnet Core 2.0 Preview 1, on Ubuntu 16.04)

```
var scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
scsb.Password="....";
scsb.UserID="sa";
scsb.DataSource="localhost";
scsb.InitialCatalog="test";
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(scsb.ConnectionString)) 
{
    conn.Open();
    using(var tran=conn.BeginTransaction()) {
        using(var comm = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM pf_ServiceHeartbeat WHERE ServiceName = @ServiceName AND MachineName = @MachineName", conn, tran)) {
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceName", "PopForums.Email.EmailApplicationService");
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineName", "MACHINENAME");
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comm.CommandText="INSERT INTO pf_ServiceHeartbeat (ServiceName, MachineName, LastRun) VALUES (@ServiceName, @MachineName, @LastRun)";
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastRun", DateTime.Now);
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        tran.Commit();
    }
}
```

Works fine every time I run it, **with, or without the transaction**

Since I don't see any difference from your implementation with `SqlObjects`, maybe you should try working directly with ADO.NET instead? Fewer intermediary levels to cause bugs.

Comment: You have not set the primary key to be clustered? If you do does that make any difference?

Comment: MSSQL by default creates primary keys as clustered indexes. `CLUSTERED` therefore is superfluous. Try it without, and check with, say, DBeaver, whether it's a clustered or non-clustered index. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706992/database-primary-key-clustered-or-nonclustered . Regardless, it works.