# Append columns from one data table to another data table

Tags: c#, datatable

I have multiple data tables(upto 28) in C# and I want to append all their columns in one data table(with data).
Example:
datatables are: DT1,DT2,DT3 and so on
Number of Columns in these respective data tables: N1,N2,N3 and so on
Output: One data table DT with total columns N1+N2+N3+... and all the data from the above data tables.
Thanks.
**Edit:**
My tables have clustered primary keys.

Comment: so what type of data in your column n1,n2, n3? its int, string, double or any else?

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278978/combining-n-datatables-into-a-single-datatable

Comment: @ershoaib the data can be of any type, each table have around 100 columns so in short I want to get a table consisting of around 2000 columns that includes all the DT1,DT2 etc. The number of rows will be same in the all tables.

Comment: if your have 3 datatables with each of 5 columns so your want 15 coulmns in resulting datatable or only 5 column with concatenating of each of respective column in all 3 datatable

Comment: @ershoaib the solution in the link cannot be implemented in my case as I have clustered primary key

Comment: @NiranjanKala in that case the primary key is one column, I have a clustered primary key

Comment: @ershoaib I need 15 columns. for example i have 3 datatables with 5 columns each and 10 rows in all three datatables, I need a datatable with 15 columns and 10 rows

Comment: @DIVIJ: you can take idea from that code and modify according to your requirement. It will make you move forward to complete your task.

Comment: clustered primary key and primary key are same read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706992/database-primary-key-clustered-or-nonclustered but if your clustered index is rather than primary key then you please mention in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var all = new DataTable();

all.Merge(DT1);
all.Merge(DT2);
all.Merge(DT2);
```

...
better to use in a loop.